# LibGDX - flickering occures when setting a camera

Tags: box2d, libgdx, orthographic

I'm trying to divide my program into model and view. At first I controlled a camera based on input and everything worked fine. Now I decided to create a `CameraModel` class and update the real camera based on properties of `CameraModel`. Problem occurs when I create a new Box2D Body - then screen flickers. Maybe it's not a camera issue, but it only happens when I'm using this code:

```
CameraModel model = level01.getCameraModel();
camera.up.set(model.getUp());
camera.position.set(model.getPosition());
camera.zoom = model.getZoom();
```

...instead of this:

```
Body playerModel = level01.getPlayer().getBody();
Vector2 Pos = playerModel.getPosition();
Vector3 wv = new Vector3(Pos.x,Pos.y,0.0f);
camera.up.x = (float) Math.cos(playerModel.getAngle());
camera.up.y = (float) Math.sin(playerModel.getAngle());
camera.position.x = wv.x + camera.up.x * 200f;
camera.position.y = wv.y + camera.up.y * 200f;
```

To be exact only when I'm using this line `camera.position.set(model.getPosition());`.Every other property is set without trouble.
What could cause the flickering?

Comment: Do you use any kind of conversion ratio from pixel to meter (box2d units)? Is that where the value 200 comes from? Why do you have the up-vector of the camera in your position calculation?

Comment: @noone Up vector is there because I do not need to center the camera on an object but rather show that object in lower part of a screen. Thanks for your interest :) but I solved it already - I was passing actual vectors, not copies somewhere else in a code. I'm just waiting for 20:20 so I can post my answer :D .. too low reputation I have :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had a messy code and was passing actual vectors, not copies... So view was jumping very very fast.